# access token user_groups not there

Tags: facebook, facebook-access-token

I want the feed of some secret Groups i am in. I used to use the following line to retrieve data

https://graph.facebook.com//feed?access_token=

with access_token for user_groups which  i used to take from https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer.

Now i cant do it because the option user_groups for access token isn't there. What can i do as alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `user_groups` permission is deprecated.

See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_4

> The user_groups permission has been deprecated. Developers may continue to use the user_managed_groups permission to access the groups a person is the administrator of. This information is still accessed via the /v2.4/{user_id}/groups edge which is still available in v2.4.

Answer (score 2):

They only way to do go around it is to use the group API explorer. Go to tools and support and click application and choose "API explorer" and before clicking get access token, change the version from 2.4 to 2.0 and click get access token. Now you can choose the user_groups option.  I hope that helps, it make facebook auto poster program completely useless with out the groups!

Comment: dude, you are awesome